# Overflowing anchor not clickable

Tags: css, overflow, anchor, clickable

I have some paragraphs inside a div and some of the words are wrapped in anchor tags.
The paragraphs use white-space: nowrap, which causes them to overflow out of the div's boundaries (which is what I intend to do). Problem is, the overflow is visible but anchors are not clickable.

This is probably by design, but still, does anyone know of a way to make the overflowing anchors clickable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Forgot to mention, with IE8 you can click. Firefox and Chrome, not.

Comment: For a sample, see http://great-passage.com/?tag=all&photoId=113 . Bottom and to the right you will see a list of tags, the last of which is not clickable!

Comment: Why would you ever have text overflow a fixed div height?

Comment: Phil, not sure I understand your question. Of course text will eventually overflow a fixed size div.

Comment: looks to be related to the `<div id="rightBox" class="rightBox">` with the like button overlapping.

Comment: wow, you're right! it's not overflow related. my bad. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm... now that I understand, the problem is a different one, that I still can't fix. Namely, the anchor overflows into the territory of a sibling div, which captures the clicks. Z-index doesn't help, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of your `div#rightBox` - it contains another div inside of it, which is like this: `<div class="verticalPlaceholder"></div>`. To fix this, instead of using a vertical placeholder like this, change the HTML and CSS like so:

#### HTML

```
<div class="rightBox" id="rightBox">
    <div class="facebookLike" id="like">
        <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:20px;" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=174634935928464&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fgreat-passage.com%2F%3FphotoId%3D113&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;font=arial&amp;height=20"></iframe>
    </div>
    <!-- Deleted verticalPlaceholder div -->
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
div.facebookLike {
    bottom: 75px;        /* ADDED */
    display: block;
    margin: 6px 0 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: relative;  /* ADDED */
}
```

Comment: yep, this is a good workaround, I actually used a similar workaround using "margin-bottom"